# How do I save the output of a grid.draw() to an R variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
p.grid <- p + facet_grid(subgroup ~ ., scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")
  p.wrap <- p + facet_wrap(~ subgroup, ncol = 1, scales = "free_y") # + theme(strip.background = element_blank(), strip.text.x = element_blank())
  gp.grid <- ggplotGrob(p.grid)
  gp.wrap <- ggplotGrob(p.wrap)
  gp.wrap$heights[gp.wrap$layout[grep("panel", gp.wrap$layout$name), "t"]] <- gp.grid$heights[gp.grid$layout[grep("panel", gp.grid$layout$name), "t"]]
  res <- grid.draw(gp.wrap)
```

When you call res, the output is NULL. How do I make it so I can save the output of grid.draw to a variable? thanks!

```
> dput(p)
structure(list(data = structure(list(subgroup = c("Sex", "Sex", 
"Age", "Age", "ECOG PS", "ECOG PS", "Autoimmune Comorbidity", 
"Autoimmune Comorbidity", "Other (non-autoimmune) comorbidity", 
"Other (non-autoimmune) comorbidity", "Indication", "Indication", 
"Site", "Site", "Site", "Site", "Site", "Site", "Site", "Site"
), levels = c("Female", "Male", "≤70yrs", ">70yrs", "0", "1+", 
"No", "Yes", "No", "Yes", "Adjuvant", "Metastatic / Unresectable", 
"Cambridge", "Cardiff", "Preston", "Norwich", "Southampton", 
"Liverpool", "Taunton", "Belfast"), subgroup_level = structure(1:20, .Label = c("sex_Female", 
"sex_Male", "age_70_plus_≤70yrs", "age_70_plus_>70yrs", "ecog_combined_0", 
"ecog_combined_1+", "ai_comorbid_fact_No", "ai_comorbid_fact_Yes", 
"non_ai_comorbid_fact_No", "non_ai_comorbid_fact_Yes", "indication_combined_Adjuvant", 
"indication_combined_Metastatic / Unresectable", "site_Cambridge", 
"site_Cardiff", "site_Preston", "site_Norwich", "site_Southampton", 
"site_Liverpool", "site_Taunton", "site_Belfast"), class = "factor"), 
    ref = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, 
    TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), or = c(1, 1.64509634742592, 1, 0.55686274509808, 
    1, 0.63860667634253, 1, 0.331168831168895, 1, 0.754850088183428, 
    1, 0.544210526315799, 1, 1.42857142823592, 0.480769230768318, 
    0.336538461538461, 0.139860139860141, 0.13925729442971, 0.0961538461538676, 
    0.0910931174089458), ci_low = c(NA, 1.01180073253164, NA, 
    0.342252010939916, NA, 0.39053307262384, NA, 0.121856536513088, 
    NA, 0.44483939366837, NA, 0.328996649669723, NA, 0.390142821458164, 
    0.105070977802425, 0.0943778862839418, 0.0343866980602263, 
    0.0415693937871878, 0.0206436880910122, 0.027148799203676
    ), ci_high = c(NA, 2.68330002637703, NA, 0.900449482928369, 
    NA, 1.04179167781301, NA, 0.824632929209806, NA, 1.26746141771102, 
    NA, 0.896585533250708, NA, 4.91477064110418, 2.27969257000586, 
    1.06210553820724, 0.498676359902108, 0.396122776982895, 0.379895112775858, 
    0.258182994605781), p = c(NA, 0.0451233246077634, NA, 0.0175236724669212, 
    NA, 0.0727693465306457, NA, 0.0213671267903278, NA, 0.29127964662401, 
    NA, 0.0171837465575855, NA, 0.573048285581527, 0.339725539779928, 
    0.0731657949719134, 0.00351990273344082, 0.000497741682385097, 
    0.0014161270950308, 2.30446596873807e-05), sig = c(NA, TRUE, 
    NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, NA, TRUE, NA, FALSE, 
    FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), col = c("REF", "UP", 
    "REF", "DOWN", "REF", "INSIG", "REF", "DOWN", "REF", "INSIG", 
    "REF", "DOWN", "REF", "INSIG", "INSIG", "INSIG", "DOWN", 
    "DOWN", "DOWN", "DOWN")), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = "data.frame"), 
    layers = list(<environment>, <environment>, <environment>), 
    scales = <environment>, mapping = structure(list(x = ~or, 
        y = ~subgroup_level), class = "uneval"), theme = structure(list(
        line = structure(list(colour = "black", size = 0.545454545454545, 
            linetype = 1, lineend = "butt", arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), rect = structure(list(fill = "white", colour = "black", 
            size = 0.545454545454545, linetype = 1, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), text = structure(list(family = "", face = "plain", 
            colour = "black", size = 12, hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, 
            angle = 0, lineheight = 0.9, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), title = NULL, aspect.ratio = NULL, axis.title = NULL, 
        axis.title.x = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
            colour = NULL, size = 12, hjust = NULL, vjust = -0.2, 
            angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(3, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 3, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.x.bottom = NULL, axis.title.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = 12, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = 2, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 3, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.title.y.left = NULL, axis.title.y.right = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = 0, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 3), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = 12, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = NULL, 
            debug = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(2.4, 
            0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x.top = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, hjust = NULL, 
            vjust = 0, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 2.4, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.x.bottom = NULL, axis.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 1, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 2.4, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.text.y.left = NULL, axis.text.y.right = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 0, 2.4), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), axis.ticks = structure(list(colour = NULL, 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.ticks.x = NULL, axis.ticks.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.y = NULL, axis.ticks.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.y.right = NULL, axis.ticks.length = structure(3, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), axis.ticks.length.x = NULL, axis.ticks.length.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.x.bottom = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y = NULL, 
        axis.ticks.length.y.left = NULL, axis.ticks.length.y.right = NULL, 
        axis.line = structure(list(colour = "black", size = NULL, 
            linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), axis.line.x = NULL, axis.line.x.top = NULL, 
        axis.line.x.bottom = NULL, axis.line.y = NULL, axis.line.y.left = NULL, 
        axis.line.y.right = NULL, legend.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.margin = structure(c(6, 6, 6, 6), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
        "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.spacing = structure(0, unit = 1L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.spacing.x = NULL, legend.spacing.y = NULL, 
        legend.key = structure(list(fill = NULL, colour = NA, 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), legend.key.size = structure(0.5, unit = 1L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.key.height = NULL, legend.key.width = NULL, 
        legend.text = structure(list(family = NULL, face = NULL, 
            colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.text.align = NULL, legend.title = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), legend.title.align = NULL, legend.position = "bottom", 
        legend.direction = "horizontal", legend.justification = "center", 
        legend.box = NULL, legend.box.just = NULL, legend.box.margin = structure(c(0, 
        0, 0, 0), unit = 1L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), legend.box.background = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), legend.box.spacing = structure(12, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.border = structure(list(fill = NA, 
            colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), panel.spacing = structure(6, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), panel.spacing.x = NULL, panel.spacing.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid = structure(list(colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major = structure(list(colour = "#f0f0f0", 
            size = NULL, linetype = NULL, lineend = NULL, arrow = FALSE, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_line", 
        "element")), panel.grid.minor = structure(list(), class = c("element_blank", 
        "element")), panel.grid.major.x = NULL, panel.grid.major.y = NULL, 
        panel.grid.minor.x = NULL, panel.grid.minor.y = NULL, 
        panel.ontop = FALSE, plot.background = structure(list(
            fill = NULL, colour = NA, size = NULL, linetype = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), plot.title = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = "bold", colour = NULL, size = 12, hjust = 0.5, 
            vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, margin = structure(c(0, 
            0, 6, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
            "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.title.position = "panel", plot.subtitle = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = 0, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(0, 0, 6, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption = structure(list(family = NULL, 
            face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(0.8, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 1, vjust = 1, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(6, 0, 0, 0), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.caption.position = "panel", plot.tag = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = structure(1.2, class = "rel"), 
            hjust = 0.5, vjust = 0.5, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), plot.tag.position = "topleft", plot.margin = structure(c(6, 
        6, 6, 6), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", "simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.background = structure(list(
            fill = "#f0f0f0", colour = "#f0f0f0", size = NULL, 
            linetype = NULL, inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_rect", 
        "element")), strip.background.x = NULL, strip.background.y = NULL, 
        strip.placement = "inside", strip.text = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = 12, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = NULL, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = structure(c(4.8, 4.8, 4.8, 4.8), unit = 8L, class = c("margin", 
            "simpleUnit", "unit", "unit_v2")), debug = NULL, 
            inherit.blank = FALSE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.text.x = NULL, strip.text.y = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = -90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element")), strip.switch.pad.grid = structure(3, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.switch.pad.wrap = structure(3, unit = 8L, class = c("simpleUnit", 
        "unit", "unit_v2")), strip.text.y.left = structure(list(
            family = NULL, face = NULL, colour = NULL, size = NULL, 
            hjust = NULL, vjust = NULL, angle = 90, lineheight = NULL, 
            margin = NULL, debug = NULL, inherit.blank = TRUE), class = c("element_text", 
        "element"))), class = c("theme", "gg"), complete = TRUE, validate = TRUE), 
    coordinates = <environment>, facet = <environment>, plot_env = <environment>, 
    labels = list(y = "", x = "Crude Odds Ratio", xintercept = "xintercept", 
        colour = "col", shape = "ref", xmax = "ci_high", xmin = "ci_low")), class = c("gg", 
"ggplot"))
```

Comment: Please check `dput(p)` in a fresh instance of R as it seems to be missing something. It would be easier if the question was completely reproducible with a simpler minimal example [MRE].

Comment: `grid.draw` is a bit like `print`. It simply draws the `gp.wrap` object, so `gp.wrap` is already the reproducible version of `res`. What is it that you want to do with `res` that you can't do with `gp.wrap`?